# Unable to get instance metadata in Azure Stack VM Instance

Tags: azure, azure-stack

In any Azure instance I can easily fetch instance meta data from IMDS urls like below-

```
curl -H 'Metadata: true' http://169.254.169.254/metadata/instance?api-version=2017-12-01&format=text
```

But when I am trying the same from Azure Stack, I am getting following error in response of every metadata url request-

Error Response: {"Message":"Error in config data"}

How can I get information like VM Id, Container Id, Resource Group Name etc. in Azure Stack Instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure Stack doesn't support Azure Instance Metadata Service.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-stack/user/azure-stack-vm-considerations

Comment: There must be some alternative way to get this information...??

Comment: The only way to get own information is to access to ARM or Azure Stack API with Service Principle from a virtual machine.